# How do I remove the white space above my images in an HTML email?

Tags: css, image, html-table, html-email, removing-whitespace

I have searched the web and this sight and tried every possible solution and still can't figure out why Outlook 2007-2013 is creating a white strip above my images.

Here is a link to the full email: http://www3.districtadministration.com/mailing/Templates/da-webinar-archives.html

Here is my code:

```
<table id="webinars" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border:1px solid #e6e6e6;">
    <tr style="background-color:#f2f2f2;border-bottom:#e6e6e6;">
        <td class="items" style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#333333;line-height:20px;padding:10px;">
        <a href="[WEBINAR TITLE #1]" target="_blank" style="color:#333333;"><strong>Enter webinar title here</strong></a><br />
        Sponsored by add sponsor
        </td>

        <td width="145" align="left" class="watchnow" style="padding-left:10px;"><a href="[WEBINAR TITLE #1]" target="_blank"><img src="http://www3.districtadministration.com/mailing/webinar13/images/btn_watchnow.jpg" alt="[button] Watch Now" width="125" height="35" border="0" /></a>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="border-bottom:#e6e6e6;">
        <td class="items" style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#333333;line-height:20px;padding:10px;">
        <a href="[WEBINAR TITLE #2]" target="_blank" style="color:#333333;"><strong>Enter webinar title here</strong></a><br />
        Sponsored by add sponsor
        </td>

        <td width="145" align="left" class="watchnow" style="padding-left:10px;"><a href="[WEBINAR TITLE #2]" target="_blank"><img src="http://www3.districtadministration.com/mailing/webinar13/images/btn_watchnow.jpg" alt="[button] Watch Now" width="125" height="35" border="0" /></a>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="background-color:#f2f2f2;border-bottom:#e6e6e6;">
        <td class="items" style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#333333;line-height:20px;padding:10px;">
        <a href="[WEBINAR TITLE #3]" target="_blank" style="color:#333333;"><strong>Enter webinar title here</strong></a><br />
        Sponsored by add sponsor
        </td>

        <td width="145" align="left" class="watchnow" style="padding-left:10px;"><a href="[WEBINAR TITLE #3]" target="_blank"><img src="http://www3.districtadministration.com/mailing/webinar13/images/btn_watchnow.jpg" alt="[button] Watch Now" width="125" height="35" border="0" /></a>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="border-bottom:#e6e6e6;">
        <td class="items" style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#333333;line-height:20px;padding:10px;">
        <a href="[WEBINAR TITLE #4]" target="_blank" style="color:#333333;"><strong>Enter webinar title here</strong></a><br />
        Sponsored by add sponsor
        </td>

        <td width="145" align="left" class="watchnow" style="padding-left:10px;"><a href="[WEBINAR TITLE #4]" target="_blank"><img src="http://www3.districtadministration.com/mailing/webinar13/images/btn_watchnow.jpg" alt="[button] Watch Now" width="125" height="35" border="0" /></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to add display:block to each of your images.

Old code:
    `<img src="http://www3.districtadministration.com/mailing/webinar13/images/btn_watchnow.jpg" alt="[button] Watch Now" width="125" height="35" border="0" />`

New code:
    `<img src="http://www3.districtadministration.com/mailing/webinar13/images/btn_watchnow.jpg" alt="[button] Watch Now" width="125" height="35" border="0" style="display:block;" />`

Comment: You may also need to add style="border-collapse: collapse" to your table as well

Comment: Excellent! I think it was adding the border-collapse that helped. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks John! I'm still learning my way around here. Didn't even realize there was such a thing lol

Answer (score 0):

```
<img alt="Image Description Goes Here" border="0" src="http://www.your-image-url-goes-here.jpg" 
width="600" height="176" style="padding:0px; display: block; line-height: 0px; font-size: 0px; border:0px;" 
align="top">
```

You need to have the `... align="top" ...` code in it. This forces the image to align at the top. By setting all of the other code dimensions to `0px` it specifies the white space to be `0px`. Also, the `display:block` is very important in removing the white space as well so the browser knows how to display the layout and format of the pictures.

I tested this code and it removed the white space in Gmail, AOL, Yahoo, Hotmail, and my remote Outlook Email Account. Hopefully this helps!